# Keep specific columns of list based on boolean Array

Tags: python, arrays, list

In Python I have a list with column names that has the following form:

```
columns_names = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4', 'example5']
```

and an array which describes which columns should be used and has the following form:

```
columns_used = [False False True False True]
```

I want to create a new list that contains only the columns that I would like to use (the array value is True).

```
columns_names_used = ['example3', 'example5']
```

Comment: Are you using anything on top of Python?  `pandas`, `scipy`, `numpy` etc?

Comment: `[column_names[i] for i in range(len(column_names)) if columns_used[i]]
`

Comment: Yes, I use all of them.

Comment: If you have some dataframe `df`, you can do `df.columns[columns_used]` to get the columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply :

```
[v for i,v in enumerate(column_names) if columns_used[i] == True] # ['example3', 'example5']
```